# Causes of hard drive SMART failure?

Tags: hardware, memory, hard-drive, smart

Specifically, can faulty system memory cause a hard drive SMART failure and can a bad hard drive connector cause a SMART failure?

Comment: I ask this because I have a laptop that has had 3 hard drives suffer smart failures in quite close succession, a few months apart. Any ideas what I should be looking at? Aside from binning this laptop that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that the answer to both questions is no, because SMART is handled internally by the disk and should be independent of the rest of the system.

Comment: Yes, the answers are no.